# Unable to access published programs on TS web access - win server 2008 OS

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am using the TS Web Access feature provided by windows server 2008 to publish programs so that they can be accessed  over internet using RDC client. I am able to access the programs from the intranet domain . However, when i try from outside the college network, i am only able to see the published programs but not connect to them as i get an error saying "Remote computer cannot be connected. The certificate subject name and the gateway address requested do not match." .
pls note that i have created a self -signed certificate and installed on server myself.
Also, i am using the direct IPAddress of the server as the gateway address.

Since i am able to access programs from with domain , i suspect it to be a simple setting with gateway or certificate. Please let me know if any further info is required on this..any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Check the following link, and look for section Certificate identity mismatch

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112224750/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2008/12/18/ts-gateway-certificates-part-iii-connection-time-issues-related-to-ts-gateway-certificates.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. The link provided above was very useful.
Once i got a DNS entry pointing to my Server IP, i used that address to create   a new certificate using active directory certificate services role provided by win server 2008. I then saved this certificate in trusted root certification authorities on the client machine. Then everything just worked fine.

Comment: @varun - Then you should tick the answer.